# Write Cell Value to Array and Print Array Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a Sub to work which does the following:

1. Searches Column F for cells that contain the word "Total"
2. Writes the value from the adjacent cell of the first found instance of "Total" to an array
3. Continues looking for "Total" in column F and writing adjacent values to the array
4. Prints the values of the array in the second column of Sheet2 with no blank cells between each value.

What I have so far is:

```
Sub MatrixFill()
    Dim I as Integer, lrow as Long, rng as Range, cell as Range, size as Integer

    'Find # of cells in column F that have "Total" to size the array'
    size = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F1:F9999"), "Total")

    'Resize the array to the amount of cells that contained "Total"'
    ReDim arrVal(1 to size) as Long

    lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range (F1:F9999" & lrow)

    'Select the cell adjacent to each cell in the F column which contains "Total" and write to the array"
    For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Total", vbTextCompare) > 0  Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
            arrVal(I) = ActiveCell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell

    'Write the values from the array to the second sheet in the workbook in column B'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    For i = LBound(arrVal) To UBound(arrVal)
       Cells(2, 0+i).Select
       Debug.Print i, arrVal(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` needs to be `lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` , and `Set rng = Range (F1:F9999" & lrow)` you meant to use `Set rng = Range("F1:F" & lrow)`

Comment: @ShaiRado, thank you for your helpful comment. I have incorporated the changes you mentioned into the code. However, I am receiving a run-time error 9 on the "arrVal(i)=ActiveCell.Value" line. This line is where I try to assign the value in the cell to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after something like the code below, see notes inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatrixFill()

    Dim i As Integer, lrow As Long, Rng As Range, cell As Range, size As Integer

    'Find # of cells in column F that have "Total" to size the array'
    size = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("F1:F9999"), "Total")

    'Resize the array to the amount of cells that contained "Total"'
    ReDim arrVal(1 To size) As Long

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Range("F1:F" & lrow)

    i = 0 ' start point array
    'Select the cell adjacent to each cell in the F column which contains "Total" and write to the array"
    For Each cell In Rng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Total", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            arrVal(i) = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value ' <-- I think you meant to use adjacent column (not row)
        End If
    Next cell

    'Write the values from the array to the second sheet in the workbook in column B'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(i, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrVal) ' <-- write the entire array at once (without a loop)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. I see the mistake I made when assigning the values from the offset cell to the array. There is a 'type-mismatch error' showing for line "If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Total", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then". Do you have an idea of why this might be happening?

Comment: @PepperBrooks do you have errors in the column, like `#N/A`,`#Value`?

Comment: @ScottCraner. Thank you for your reply. Yes, there was an #N/A error in one of the cells of the column. I removed that which solved the type-mismatch error of the macro. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @PepperBrooks is the code working now as you intended?

Comment: The code now gives a run-time 1004 error on line "arrVal(I)=ActiveCell(o,1).Value". Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: @PepperBrooks  you are not using my code ? Check your code, I don't use activeCell

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. That line I mentioned was incorrect for the code given by ShaiRado. Thank you both to ShaiRado and @ScottCraner for your thoughtful assistance!

Comment: @ScottCraner. Is there a way to skip over #N/A cells in the For statement? Would "If IsError(ActiveCell.Value) Then Next Cell" work?

Comment: Wrap the current If in another if: `IF Not IsError(cell.value) then`